# Microsoft work or school account sign out with oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth, authorization, windows-live-id

I would like to sign out user from **Microsoft Work or School Account** via link om my site using **oauth** with redirect link specified.
Is there any possibility to do that and what is the logout uri? Is there something corresponding to the uri in personal account: "https://login.live.com/oauth20_logout.srf"